# two-column, top-aligned, fixed width layout

Tags: html, ios, css, embed

I am trying to create a two-column, top-aligned, fixed width layout for some data to embed within other text in a WebView for an iPhone app. I need the first column to be of a fixed width so that all items in the second column will be neatly aligned.
I have tried many solutions from SO and the Net using HTML, CSS or both, and have always failed. Column width isn't kept and entries do not top-align.

Content example:

**In the first column:**

```
Address  
Distance  
Ticket price
```

**In the second column:**

```
12-26-3 Kami Itabashi, Itabashi-ku, Tokyo  
23km   
350 Yen
```

This is my very first question, so please have mercy.

I can provide if necessary my CSS style sheet.

Comment: create a basic [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to understand what went wrong in the code

Comment: can u give me link of your screenshoot image

Comment: Rohit, here is a screenshot.http://rempu.modwest.com/photo/SS.png

Comment: GilbertOOi, jsfiddle did it, thanks. How do I credit you an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the question is not clear ,but anyway :

`HTML`

```
<div class="frame">
    <div class="l">
        <p>Address</p>
        <p>Distance</p>
        <p>Ticket<span>price</span></p>
    </div>    
    <div class="r">
        <p><span class="number">12-26-3</span>Kami Itabashi, Itabashi-ku, Tokyo  </p>
        <p><span class="number">23km</span></p>
        <p><span class="number">350</span>Yen</p>
     </div>    

</div>
```

`CSS`

```
p{
    height:20px;
    color:#000000;
    margin: 20px 0px;
    color:#000000;
}
.frame{
    width:310px;
    height:150px;
    background:#A0A0A0;
}
.number{
    color:#8D0000;
}
.l{
 float:left;   
}

.r{
    width: 220px;
    float:right;   
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xwmHu/3/)

Comment: Thanks, Pumpkinpro. I solved the problem by myself,  but your solution is cleaner.